# Observation from Lax's proof of Change of Variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the following observation near the bottom of p. 498 from [Lax's proof of the change of variables theorem](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~jyhhaur/teaching/advancedcalculusII2013spring/Lax.pdf):

**Observation:** *The integrand in (2.4) can be written as the following determinant:*

$$
\det(Dg(\varphi),D\varphi_2,\dots,D\varphi_n).
$$

Note that $\varphi(x) = y$ is a once differentiable mapping from $n$-dimensional $x$ space to $n$-dimensional $y$ space. Here $g$ is once differentiable as a map from $n$-dimensional $y$ space to $\Bbb R$, and $D$ denotes the gradient with respect to $x$.

The integrand in (2.4) isn't exactly relevant to my question which is about the first line of Lax's proof of this observation, though you can see Lax's paper to check (2.4) if you like. I have included all the information relevant to my question here.

Here is the first line of Lax's proof of this observation:

*By the chain rule,*
$$
Dg(\varphi) = \sum_{j=1}^n(\partial_{y_j} g)D\varphi_j.
$$
This is where I am having trouble. I can't see how he is applying the chain rule here. Note that Lax's definition of the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose element in the $i$th row and $j$th column is $\partial \varphi_j/\partial x_i$. Thus the $j$th column of the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$ is $D\varphi_j$. Hence my question:

> How is Lax applying the chain rule here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so $D(g \circ \varphi): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. If we take the $i$th component, we have using the ordinary chain rule for partial derivatives:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (g \circ \varphi) = \sum_j \frac{\partial g}{\partial \varphi_j} \frac{\partial \varphi_j}{\partial x_i} $$
Since $y_j=\varphi_j(x)$, we then put the components back together and find
$$ D(g \circ \varphi) = \sum_j (\partial_{y_j} g) D\varphi_j $$
as we want.

Comment: I challenge this premise that $D(g\circ\varphi):\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$. Shouldn't it be $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yeah, slip of the keyboard. The point is that it's a gradient, so a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$. (And hence can be considered as a vector in $(\mathbb{R}^n)^* = \mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: I see. So though we can interpret the gradient as an element of $\Bbb R^n$, we should probably be more precise and replace $D(g\circ\varphi)$ with $D(g\circ\varphi)^T$ in the claim of the observation.

Comment: Well, all the $D\varphi_i$ are also linear functionals, rather than vectors, so here the determinant is acting as a multilinear map on $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, rather than its usual version of acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But the dual space is isomorphic to the original, so it has all the same properties as usual.